# How to fix "django.core.exceptions.FieldError:" when querying with "_startswith" filter in django views?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to get a queryset where the username starts with some name.

I have implemented the following code :

```
def searchUsers(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        uname = request.GET['name']
        print(uname)
        user = User_Master.objects.filter(username_startswith = uname.title())
        usr_jsn = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', user))
        return JsonResponse(usr_jsn)
```

Ajax call is succesfully running and I'm getting the searchkeyword printed in terminal.

But the error I'm getting is because of "_startswith" filter. This is the part from traceback.

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'username_startswith' into field. Choices are: contact_no, created_at, created_by, department, email, id, industry_segment, password, status, updated_at, updated_by, username
```

I have searched for my problem but none of the solutions worked.

Comment: You need two underscores: `username__startswith`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `dundee(__) double underscore` for lookups

```
user = User_Master.objects.filter(username__startswith = uname.title())
```

Comment: Oh man, thankyou so much .... I guess working continuosly exhausts your mind :p .... How can i be so stupid. I even checked the documentation and still couldn't figure it out. Much appreciated